# Does the PS4 support SimulView?

Tags: ps4, stereo-3d

Does the PS4 support *[SimulView](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/accessories/sony-playstation-3d-display-ps3/simul-view.html)* (the feature which allows two players to see different thinks on one single TV utilizing 3D techniques) like the PS3?

Comment: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/Does-the-PS4-support-SimulView-after-the-update/td-p/44175482

Answer (score 1):

From the [Playstation Help page about SimulView](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/apps---features/other/about-simulview-on-the-playstation-3d-display/):

> **What games support the SimulView feature as of launch? Will future games support SimulView?**
>
> The following titles are supported:
>
> - MotorStorm: 3D Rift
> - MotorStorm Apocalypse
> - Gran Turismo 5
> - Killzone 3
> - Super Stardust HD
> - MLB 12: The Show
> - MLB 13: The Show
>
> **There are currently no plans for future games to support SimulView.**

Since these games are all for PS3, this seems to indicate that there is no need for PS4 to support SimulView.

Comment: That's sad... It's such a nice feature! However it's not a definite statement. There is still little hope left...

Comment: @Rob I agree. I messed with Simulview when it was on display at Gamestop about 5 years ago and thought it was a cool concept, but it doesn't seem like it's a top priority for Sony at the moment.